# Consulta condicionales sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, else

Tengo una tabla,en donde hagan de cuenta que su hogar es la familia1 **(f1)** : Mama o Papa (Jefe de Hogar), Conyuge e Hijo entonces seria una familia Biparental i.e..

Jefe de hogar + conyuge / companero + Hijo(a) = Biparental

**Cada uno de ustedes tiene un id que seria la clave primaria, pero tiene el mismo id de la familia (id_focalizacion), hasta ahi todo bien?**

ok

En la familia 2 **(f2)** tenemos solo al Jefe de Hogar y el Hijo por lo tanto es una familia Monoparental.

jefe de hogar + Hijo(a) = Biparental

En resumen, tenemos.

Familia Biparental = Jefe de Hogar, Conyuge / Companero, Hijo(a)

Familia Monoparental = Jefe de Hogar, Hijo(a)

Esta seria la base de datos la llamaremos bdfamilias

[image: bdfamilias]

*Tengo la tarea de identificar que tipo de familia es, por cada id de focalizacion, claro esta que son mas de 2 familias y **para cada una debo filtrar y saber si es biparental o monoparental**, en una columna aparte.*

Para al final tener lo siguiente

[image: Output]

Agradezco su colaboracion.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

[Aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74d90c/6/0) te propongo una solución al problema, que además generaliza al caso en que pueda haber familias multiparentales (más de dos progenitores) o casos raros (sin ningún progenitor).

El truco consiste en hacer una agrupación identificando por para `id_focalizacion` si se trata de un cabeza-familia o no, para contar el total:

```
select id_focalizacion, 
(case when parentesco = 'jefe-de-hogar'
       or parentesco = 'conyuge' 
      then 'cabeza-familia'
      else 'hijo' end) cabeza_familia_o_hijo, 
 count(*) numero_miembros
 from family
   where parentesco in ('jefe-de-hogar', 'conyuge')
 group by  id_focalizacion, 
(case when parentesco = 'jefe-de-hogar'
       or parentesco = 'conyuge' 
      then 'cabeza-familia'
      else 'hijo' end)
```

Una vez que tenemos eso, podemos *instrumentalizar* esta consulta y usarla como subconsulta de una que ya usa el dato numero_miembros para saber si es monoparental, biparental u otra cosa más rara:

```
select t1.id_focalizacion, 
(case when t1.numero_miembros = 1 
 then 'monoparental' 
 when t1.numero_miembros = 2 
 then 'biparental'
 when t1.numero_miembros > 2 
 then 'multiparental' 
 else 'desconocido' end) tipo_familia
 from
 (
select id_focalizacion, 
(case when parentesco = 'jefe-de-hogar'
       or parentesco = 'conyuge' 
      then 'cabeza-familia'
      else 'hijo' end) cabeza_familia_o_hijo, 
 count(*) numero_miembros
 from family
   where parentesco in ('jefe-de-hogar', 'conyuge')
 group by  id_focalizacion, 
(case when parentesco = 'jefe-de-hogar'
       or parentesco = 'conyuge' 
      then 'cabeza-familia'
      else 'hijo' end) 
   ) t1;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Raul, me funciono, aunque tengo un reto real, estaba metiendo el codigo mal, llevo 15 dias en sql.

Answer (score -1):

Estaba intentando este codigo

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_focalizacion, 
CASE 
WHEN (parentesco= 'Jefe Grupo Familiar' OR parentesco= 'Conyuge / Compañero' OR parentesco= 'Hijo(a)') THEN 'Nuclear Biparental'
WHEN (parentesco= 'Jefe Grupo Familiar' OR parentesco='Hijo(a)') THEN 'Nuclear Monoparental'
WHEN (parentesco= 'Jefe Grupo Familiar' OR parentesco='Conyuge / Compañero' OR parentesco='Hijo(a)' OR parentesco='Nieto(a)' OR parentesco='Hermano(a)'
OR parentesco='Abuelo(a)' OR parentesco='Padre / Madre' OR parentesco='Pariente' OR parentesco='Primo(a)' OR parentesco='Sobrino(a)' OR parentesco='Suegro(a)'
OR parentesco='Tio(a)') THEN 'Biparental Extenso'
WHEN (parentesco='Jefe Grupo Familiar' OR parentesco='Conyuge / Compañero' OR parentesco='Hijo(a)' OR parentesco='Hermano(a)' OR parentesco='Abuelo(a)'
OR parentesco='Nieto(a)' OR parentesco='Padre / Madre' OR parentesco='Pariente' OR parentesco='Primo(a)' OR parentesco='Sobrino' OR parentesco='Suegro(a)' OR
parentesco='Tio(a)') THEN 'Monoparental Extenso'
WHEN (parentesco='Jefe Grupo Familiar' OR parentesco='Conyuge / Compañero' OR parentesco='Hijo(a)' OR parentesco='Amigo(a)' OR parentesco='Cuñado(a)' 
OR parentesco='Hijastro(a)' OR parentesco='Padrastro / Madrastra' OR parentesco='Yerno / Nuera') THEN 'Biparental Compuesto' 
ELSE 'Monoparental Compuesto'
END AS tipofamilia
FROM bdmifamilia;
```

Pero no estaba ni cerca debido a que me filtraba mal y ademas, hacia la consulta por cada fila sin haberla agrupado.

Ya que lograste la subconsulta, ahora me queda dividirlos en Biparental Extenso, Biparental Compuesto, Monoparental Extenso, Monoparental compuesto, donde se cumplan las siguientes condiciones para el mismo conteo, donde en la columna 'parentesco' incluya los siguientes, es decir, si era ***Biparental***, ahora debe reemplazarse por ***Biparental Extenso***, si la busqueda encuentra ademas de los ***COMPLETADOS***, alguno como abuelo(a), o , tío(a), primo(a) . asi como se definen abajo.

Familia

- Biparental: jefe de grupo familiar + cónyuge/compañero + hijo(a) + hijo (a) **COMPLETADO**
- Monoparental: jefe de grupo familiar + hijo(a) + hijo(a) **COMPLETADO**

Familia Amplia:

- Biparental extenso: jefe de grupo familiar + cónyuge/compañero + hijo(a) + hijo (a) + hermano(a) + abuelo(a) + nieto(a) + padre/madre + pariente + primo(a) + sobrino(a) + suegro(a) + tío(a)
- Biparental compuesto: jefe de grupo familiar + cónyuge/compañero + hijo(a) + hijo (a) + amigo(a) + cuñado(a) + hijastro(a) + padrastro/madrastra + yerno/nuera
- Monoparental extenso: jefe de grupo familiar + hijo(a) + hijo(a) + hermano(a) + abuelo(a) + nieto(a) + padre/madre + pariente + primo(a) + sobrino(a) + suegro(a) + tío(a)
- Monoparental compuesto: jefe de grupo familiar + hijo(a) + hijo(a) + amigo(a) + cuñado(a) + hijastro(a) + padrastro/madrastra + yerno/nuera

Comment: No entiendo esta respuesta...

Comment: A ver, @Christian, ésto no es un foro: la pregunta que hiciste ya está respondida. Puedes plantear otra pregunta, pero yo no puedo añadir una respuesta a esta